# Trigger 'click' event for dynamic data

Tags: jquery, triggers, delegates

I have a series of checkboxes that are created dynamically when they are read from a .csv file.  After a series of checkboxes is made, another is added which is 'Select All'.  The idea is that the 'select all' checkbox, which is also created dynamically, when checked, will check all of the checkboxes above it.  Each checkbox is set to put it's name attribute within a textarea down below.

Here is a sample of what the HTML looks like **after** it is pulled from the csv file.

```
<div class="checkboxes">
   <input type="checkbox" class="article" name="Article 1" />Article 1 <br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="article" name="Article 2" />Article 2 <br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="select-all" />Select all
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Right now I am using .delegate on the article checkboxes and select-all to register a click event

```
 //clicking dynamically created input.article
 $('div.checkboxes').delegate('input.article','click',function(){
     $('textarea').val($(this).attr('name') + '/n');  //adds 'name' attr and a linebreak
 });

 //clicking dynamically created select-all
 $('div.checkboxes').delegate('input.select-all','click',function(){
     $('div.checkboxes').find('input.article').prop('checked',true); //works to select all articles
 });
```

The problem is, that even tho 'select-all' does check all of the article checkboxes, it doesn't actually fire the line:

```
    $('textarea').val($(this).attr('name') + '/n');  //adds 'name' attr and a linebrea
```

The name attribute is not being placed within the textarea.

Again, all of the article checkboxes are being checked by 'Select-all'.  It's just 'triggering' a 'click' event.

Within textarea, ideally this would show up:

Article 1

Article 2

How can this be accomplished?

Thank you for your help.

RESOLVED:

```
  $('div.checkboxes').delegate('input.select-all','click',function(){

       if ($(this).is(':checked')){

      $('input.article[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);   
      $('input.article[type=checkbox]').each( function(){
        $(this).trigger('click');
      });
       }
  });
```

Vielen Dank.

Comment: What should be displayed in your `<textarea/>` after clicking "Select all"?

Comment: Article 1 

Article 2

I'll add this to the original question.  thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Loop - Just a note: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method." See http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do these things but here is a simple change to your code:

```
 //clicking dynamically created input.article
 $('div.checkboxes').delegate('input.article','click',addname);

function addname(){
     $('textarea').val($(this).attr('name') + '/n');  //adds 'name' attr and a linebreak
};

 //clicking dynamically created select-all
 $('div.checkboxes').delegate('input.select-all','click',function(){
     $('div.checkboxes').find('input.article').prop('checked',true); //works to select all articles
     addname();
 });
```

NB - I notice you seem to be missing a lot of `;`s, was this a copy typo or are you missing them in your code?